# Swift core data: why do I need to unwrap when setting optional attribute values?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, forced-unwrapping

I have a core data model that contains mainly optional attributes. I assumed then that I would not need to unwrap the values that I am assigning to these optional attributes.  e.g. I thought I would be able to do:

```
myEntity.gravity = currentOrder.gravity
```

(myEntity.gravity being optional)

However, Swift still requires me to unwrap currentOrder.gravity. I would have thought given that the variable I am assigning to is optional that I would not need to unwrap this.

Update:

Here is the definition of one of the core data entities I am describing:

```
    <attribute name="percentComplete" optional="YES" attributeType="Float" defaultValueString="0.0" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
```

The entity itself:

```
    <entity name="AircraftMeasurementsCD" representedClassName="AircraftMeasurementsCD" syncable="YES" codeGenerationType="class">
```

Comment: What you're describing should be true. I suspect that `myEntity` or `currentOrder` aren't defined quite the way you think they are. You should show the exact definitions of these from your code.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier I just added the definitions of one of the optional attributes along with the entity it belongs to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're equivocating on the word "optional".
The word "optional" in the attribute description `optional="YES"` is not the same as, and has nothing to do with, the Swift Optional enum type.

The former is merely the ordinary English word "optional", meaning "not required" — for a particular entity, there might or might not be a value for this attribute, which is a `Float`, but even if there isn't, it's a valid entity. Nothing in the story says that this attribute's *type* is `Optional<Float>`. Its type is `Float`. And you can't assign a Swift Optional where its wrapped type is expected; you have to unwrap it.

Indeed, this point is made very explicitly by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/configuring_attributes?language=objc):

> Optional attributes aren’t required to have a value when saved to the persistent store. Attributes are optional by default.
>   Core Data optionals *aren’t the same as Swift optionals.* [My italics.]

Comment: thanks for the response - so in this case there is no way to avoid unwrapping these? This issue I'm facing is that I have a fairly lengthy list of attributes (around 70 in total) and it appears i need to unwrap each one individually

Comment: I don't know anything about why `currentOrder.gravity` is an Optional, because you have not told me. Maybe it needs to be, maybe it doesn't; I have no way of knowing, that isn't part of your question, either. Maybe you'd like to ask a different question about architecting your types? Meanwhile, what you _did_ ask is why an `Optional<Float>` cannot be assigned directly to `myEntity.gravity` and I think I answered that.

Comment: fair enough, understood